# Best way to find a full word on a string

Tags: java, string

I'm doing a project and I need to find a full word in string for example `"Hello Stackoverflow, have a nice day"` I want to know if the word `"over"` is in that string. Also should i use `toLowerCase()` to avoid problems?

Comment: indexof() but i dont like it, i know there are many ways to do it so its a question about perfomance.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: Rather than `indexOf()` I recommend `String.contains()`. If you want to find `over` no matter if it says `Stackoverflow` or `Stack Overflow`, you are correct, `toLowerCase()` is a good option.

Comment: @NicolasAlbarracin, first, don’t care about performance until your users start complaining about the time your program runs, second, if you really, really want an efficient implementation, you may look into the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Comment: There is a Java implementtion in [the Wikipedia article I linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#Implementations).

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "Hello StackOverFlow";
if (a.indexOf("Over") >= 0)
    System.out.println("Found");
else
    System.out.println("Not Found");
```

Use `toLowerCase()` if you are unsure of the case.

Comment: what about contain there are so many options... also shouldn't over be between //b

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils in Apache Commons Lang has contains()
and containsIgnoreCase(), among many other useful utilities.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

whether to ignore case or not is up to you and what your program requires as 'correct'.  HTH

Comment: I keep getting surprised how willing some people are to depend on a third party library when the standard Java library already offers all that you need. I certainly would not want to.